# Compile-time printf format checking

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-safety, assertions

### Compile time checking of printf-like format strings

Inspired by [this open ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6815) on boost, this seeks to complete the work there

Given a printf-style format string and associated arguments, a `static_assert` is performed on whether the format string and arguments are valid.

I'm particularly interested in:

- Have I covered all possible format strings?
- Am I doing this in the most efficient way?

#### Code:

[Working example on ideone](https://ideone.com/WwfXVD)

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool checkValidFormats(const char (&fmt)[N], size_t n, char c)
{
    return n >= N ?
            false
        : fmt[n] == c ?
            true
        : checkValidFormats(fmt, n + 1, c);
}

template<class>
struct FormatSupportedType;

#define SUPPORTED_TYPE(T, Fmts) \
template<> \
struct FormatSupportedType<T> \
{ \
    constexpr static bool supports(char c) \
    { return checkValidFormats(Fmts, 0, c) \
            ? true : throw std::logic_error("invalid fmt for type"); } \
}

SUPPORTED_TYPE(char,              "c");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(int,               "d*");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(unsigned,          "u*");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(char*,             "s");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(const char*,       "s");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(std::string,       "s");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(boost::string_ref, "s");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(double,            "f");
SUPPORTED_TYPE(float,             "f");

/////////////////

constexpr bool isDigit(char c)
{
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

constexpr bool isModifier(char c)
{
    return  c == 'l' ||
            c == 'h' ||
            c == 'j' ||
            c == 'z' ||
            c == 't' ||
            c == 'L' ||
            c == '#' ||
            c == '+' ||
            c == '-' ||
            c == ' ' ||
            c == '\'' ||
            c == 'I' ||
            c == '.' ||
            c == '=' ||
            isDigit(c);
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr size_t nextNonModifier(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n)
{
    return
        n >= N ?
            throw std::logic_error("invalid format string")
        : isModifier(fmt[n]) ?
                nextNonModifier(fmt, n + 1)
        : n;
}

////////////////////

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n);
template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args);

////////////////////

template<std::size_t N, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto checkWidthAndPrecision(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T1& /*width*/, const T2& /*precision*/, const T3& /* arg */, const Ts&... args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<T1>::value &&
            std::is_integral<T2>::value,
        bool>::type
{
    return FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T3>::type>::supports(fmt[n]) &&
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1, args...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool checkWidthAndPrecision(const char (&)[N], std::size_t, const Ts&...)
{
    return false;
}

////////////////////

template<std::size_t N, typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto checkWidthOrPrecision(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T1& /*precision*/, const T2& /* arg */, const Ts&... args)
    -> typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_integral<T1>::value,
        bool>::type
{
    return FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T2>::type>::supports(fmt[n]) &&
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1, args...);
}

template<std::size_t N, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool checkWidthOrPrecision(const char (&)[N], std::size_t, const Ts&...)
{
    return false;
}

////////////////////

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n)
{
    return
        n>= N ?
            true
        : fmt[n] != '%' ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1)
        : fmt[n + 1] == '%' ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2)
        : false;
}

template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return
        n >= N ?
            throw std::logic_error("too many arguments for provided format string")

        : fmt[n] != '%' ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1, arg, args...)

        // literal percent character
        : (fmt[n + 1] == '%') ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2, arg, args...)

        // long-long modifier
        : (fmt[n + 1] == 'l' && fmt[n + 2] == 'l') ?
            FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type >::supports(fmt[n + 3]) &&
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 4, args...)

        // width & precision modifier
        : (fmt[n + 1] == '*' && fmt[n + 2] == '.' && fmt[n + 3] == '*') ?
            checkWidthAndPrecision(fmt, n + 4, arg, args...)

        // width or precision modifier
        : ((fmt[n + 1] == '.' && fmt[n + 2] == '*') || (fmt[n + 1] == '*')) ?
            checkWidthOrPrecision(fmt, (fmt[n + 1] == '.' ? n + 3 : n + 2), arg, args...)

        // other modifier
        : (isModifier(fmt[n + 1])) ?
            FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type>::supports(fmt[nextNonModifier(fmt, n + 2)]) &&
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, nextNonModifier(fmt, n + 2) + 1, args...)

        // no modifier
        : FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type>::supports(fmt[n + 1]) &&
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2, args...);
}

template<std::size_t N, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormat(const char (&fmt)[N], const Ts&... args)
{
    return checkFormatHelper(fmt, 0, args...);
}

// printing...

void add(boost::format&)
{ }

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void add(boost::format& f, const T& arg, const Ts&... ts)
{
    f % arg;
    add(f, ts...);
}

#define LOG(fmt, ...) \
    { \
        static_assert(checkFormat(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__), "Format is incorrect"); \
        boost::format f(fmt); \
        add(f, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        std::cout << f.str() << std::endl; \
    }

int main()
{
    // char
    LOG("%c", 'x');

    // integral
    LOG("%d", -123);
    LOG("%ld", -123);
    LOG("%u", 123u);
    LOG("%lu", 123u);

    // strings
    LOG("%s", "hello world");
    { const char* s = "hello world"; LOG("%s", s); }
    { std::string s = "hello world"; LOG("%s", s); }
    { std::string s = "hello world"; boost::string_ref r(s); LOG("%s", r); }

    // floating point
    LOG("%f", 1.23);
    LOG("%f", 1.23f);

    // width / precision
    LOG("%02d", 1);
    LOG("%.2d", 123);
    LOG("% 3s", "hello");
    LOG("% 3s", "yo");
    LOG("%.3s", "hello");
    LOG("%.3s", "yo");

    // incorrect format string
    // LOG("%f", 1);
    // LOG("%d", 1.23);

    // not supported by boost::format
    // LOG("%*s", 3, "yo");
    // LOG("%*d", 3, 12);
    // LOG("%.*s", 3, "hello");
    // LOG("%.*d", 3, 12345);
    // LOG("%*.*s", 3, 3, "hello");
    // LOG("%*.*d", 3, 3, 12345);
}
```

#### Output:

```
x
-123
-123
123
123
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
1.230000
1.230000
01
123
 hello
 yo
hel
yo
```

#### Output when an invalid format string / argument combination is passed:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:190:9: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
         static_assert(checkFormat(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__), "Format is incorrect"); \
         ^
prog.cpp:226:5: note: in expansion of macro 'LOG'
     LOG("%f", 1);
     ^
prog.cpp:226:5:   in constexpr expansion of 'checkFormat<3u, {int}>((*"%f"), (* &1))'
prog.cpp:173:45:   in constexpr expansion of 'checkFormatHelper<3u, int, {}>((* & fmt), 0u, (* & args#0))'
prog.cpp:166:82:   in constexpr expansion of 'FormatSupportedType<int>::supports(((int)fmt[(n + 1u)]))'
prog.cpp:24:67: error: expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression
             ? true : throw std::logic_error("invalid fmt for type"); } \
                                                                   ^
prog.cpp:28:1: note: in expansion of macro 'SUPPORTED_TYPE'
 SUPPORTED_TYPE(int,               "d*");
 ^
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/85031/9357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall a nice start.
But it is by no means complete.

### The ## symbol joins the prev and the next token.

```
    static_assert(checkFormat(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__), "Format is incorrect"); \
    boost::format f(fmt); \
    add(f, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
```

<strike>So I am not sure what you are doing with it here. I would remove it completely.</strike>
@glampert pointed out that the `##` used with varargs on **GNU** is a special extension that effectively drops the proceeding comma if the argument list is empty.

### Using ternary operator as an `if/then/else`

I think your use of the ternary operator makes the code less readable.

```
return
    n>= N ?
        true
    : fmt[n] != '%' ?
        checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1)
    : fmt[n + 1] == '%' ?
        checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2)
    : false;
```

Is that as readable as:

```
if (n>= N) {
    return true;
}
else if (fmt[n] != '%') {
    return checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1);
}
else if (fmt[n + 1] == '%')
    return checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2);
}
```

I suppose its a debatable one that. But your main loop becomes a bit more obtuse. I understand you are probably doing it because of the `constexpr` requirements.

### Format Specifier:

Also the format specifier is a bit more complex than this:

```
       : fmt[n + 1] == '%' ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2)
```

The format specifier is generalized to:

```
        %[<flags>][<width>][.<precision>][<length>]<specifier>

        flags     := [-+ #0]*            // Zero or more 
        width     := <number>|'*'        // A number or a '*'
        precision := <number>|'*'
        length    := hh|h|l|ll|j|z|t|L
        specifier := d|i|u|o|x|X|f|F|e|E|g|G|a|A|c|s|p|n|%
```

So you need to use something more like the code in your main helper function (looks like a case for re-use).

#### Length

You support the long long.

```
    // long-long modifier
    : (fmt[n + 1] == 'l' && fmt[n + 2] == 'l') ?
        FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type >::supports(fmt[n + 3]) &&
        checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 4, args...)
```

But that is only one of several length specifiers.
Also you are not checking to see if the other optional parts of the format specifier is there you just assume it comes directly after the `ll`. You need your `checkValidFormats()` to be slightly more sophisticated.

#### Width/Precision

```
    // width & precision modifier
    : (fmt[n + 1] == '*' && fmt[n + 2] == '.' && fmt[n + 3] == '*') ?
        checkWidthAndPrecision(fmt, n + 4, arg, args...)

    // width or precision modifier
    : ((fmt[n + 1] == '.' && fmt[n + 2] == '*') || (fmt[n + 1] == '*')) ?
        checkWidthOrPrecision(fmt, (fmt[n + 1] == '.' ? n + 3 : n + 2), arg, args...)
```

Note these values can also be numbers. Which means you should be skipping over the number characters.

But I think your code is incorrect here. Because if the width or precision specifier is `*` then you should be expecting another runtime argument. Which means I would expect you to be checking the type of the current argument (which should be some form of integer).

### Recomendation

I would split the `checkFormatHelper()` into multiple functions that check the different parts of the format specifier.

```
template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelper(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return
        n >= N ?
            throw std::logic_error("too many arguments for provided format string")

        : fmt[n] != '%' ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 1, arg, args...)

        // literal percent character
        : (fmt[n + 1] == '%') ?
            checkFormatHelper(fmt, n + 2, arg, args...)

        // Otherwise we have a format specifier.
        // Check each part of the specifier
        : checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n + 1, arg, args...);
}

template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelperFlags(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return
         fmt[n] == '-' ? checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n+1, arg, args...)
       : fmt[n] == '+' ? checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n+1, arg, args...)
       : fmt[n] == ' ' ? checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n+1, arg, args...)
       : fmt[n] == '#' ? checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n+1, arg, args...)
       : fmt[n] == '0' ? checkFormatHelperFlags(fmt, n+1, arg, args...)
       : checkFormatHelperWidth(fmt, n, arg, args...);
}
template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelperWidth(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return
         isDigit(fmt[n]) ?
             ? checkFormatHelperPrecision(fmt, removeDigits(fmt,n) , arg, args...);
       : fmt[n] == '*'
             ? FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type>::supports("i") && checkFormatHelperPrecision(fmt, n+1, args...)
             : checkFormatHelperPrecision(fmt, n, arg, args...);
}
template<std::size_t N, class T, class... Ts>
constexpr bool checkFormatHelperPrecision(const char (&fmt)[N], std::size_t n, const T& arg, const Ts&... args)
{
    return
         fmt[n] == '.' 
            ? isDigit(fmt[n])
                 ? checkFormatHelperLength(fmt, removeDigits(fmt,n) , arg, args...);
                 : fmt[n] == '*'
                      ? FormatSupportedType< typename std::decay<T>::type>::supports("i") && checkFormatHelperLength(fmt, n+1, args...)
                      : throw std::logic_error("invalid fmt for type")
            : checkFormatHelperLength(fmt, n, arg, args...);
}
// OK now you can do the difficult ones.
// The Length Call may need to pass type information forward to the
// Specifier check.
```

Comment: Loki, it looks like the `##` operator combined with `__VA_ARGS__` is a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros) (see at the end).

Comment: `Terminator for checkFormatHelper() always returns true:` I don't think that's correct - this is the overload for where there are no more arguments. If we reach the end of the format string and there are no more args, it is valid. If we find a single `%` sign, then it's false, coz there are no more arguments. That is, it will return false if `fmt[n] == '%' && fmt[n + 1] != '%'` (ie: we're not printing a literal `%` character)

Comment: Yep. Just re-read that. You are correct.

Comment: @LokiAstari I'm not sure what the right thing to do is: update my question and make your answer a mismatch to the code, or add an answer with the latest iteration of the code based off your comments. I chose the latter. Thanks for your input, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SteveLorimer: Best to ask a new question

Comment: @LokiAstari [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85031/compile-time-printf-style-format-checking) is a new question

Comment: The terniary is needed for C++11 as it only allows one statement namely a return for constexpr functions.